# Pivot dynamic html table using mysql and php

Tags: html, html-table, pivot

This my current code.

```
<?php
$query_production ="SELECT uploadedby, uploaddate, count(uploadedby) as items, date_format(uploaddate,'%m-%d-%Y') as date FROM imsexport WHERE uploaddate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-03' GROUP BY uploadedby, date ORDER BY uploadedby";
$production = mysql_query($query_production,$prepress) or die (mysql_error());
$row_production = mysql_fetch_assoc($production);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>uploadedby</td>
      <td>uploaddate</td>
      <td>items</td>
      <td>date</td>
   </tr>
 <?php do {?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row_production['uploadedby']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_production['uploadedby']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_production['items']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_production['date']?></td>
  </tr>
```

The resulting display is:

```
 uploadedby              uploaddate           items   date
Adonis Abiera       2013-01-01 08:03:00     64  01-01-2013
Adonis Abiera       2013-01-02 05:30:00     46  01-02-2013
Aileen Alina        2013-01-02 16:29:00     15  01-02-2013
Aileen Mosende      2013-01-01 07:54:00     98  01-01-2013
Aileen Mosende      2013-01-02 06:00:00     69  01-02-2013
Ailyn Barnum        2013-01-01 09:21:00     84  01-01-2013
Ailyn Barnum        2013-01-02 09:16:00     55  01-02-2013
Alexander Dulay     2013-01-02 08:15:00     64  01-02-2013
Alfredo Santiago    2013-01-01 08:02:00     79  01-01-2013
Alfredo Santiago    2013-01-02 06:06:00     59  01-02-2013
Analyn Reyes        2013-01-01 09:04:00     65  01-01-2013
Analyn Reyes        2013-01-02 09:33:00     51  01-02-2013
Andresito Muzones   2013-01-01 08:37:00     60  01-01-2013
Andresito Muzones   2013-01-02 08:45:00     72  01-02-2013
Angelica Domingo    2013-01-01 09:28:00     68  01-01-2013
Angelica Domingo    2013-01-02 09:40:00     59  01-02-2013
Arman Romanca       2013-01-01 09:23:00     73  01-01-2013
Arman Romanca       2013-01-02 10:14:00     64  01-02-2013
Don Feliciano       2013-01-01 09:13:00     70  01-01-2013
Don Feliciano       2013-01-02 06:11:00     56  01-02-2013
```

I want to display it like this:

```
uploadedby         01-01-2013    01-02-2013
Adonis Abiera         64            46
Aileen Alina           0            15
Aileen Mosende        98            69
Ailyn Barnum          84            55
Alexander Dulay        0            64
Alfredo Santiago      79            59
Analyn Reyes          65            51
...... and so on
```

Note that there are certain records that may not exist for certain dates. ex(records for Aileen Alina and Alexander Dulay). Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to perform this in MySQL, then you would *pivot* the data using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select uploadedby,
  count(case 
        when date_format(uploaddate,'%m-%d-%Y') = '01-01-2013'
        then uploadedby end) as `01-01-2013`,
  count(case 
        when date_format(uploaddate,'%m-%d-%Y') = '01-02-2013'
        then uploadedby end) as `01-02-2013`        
from imsexport
where uploaddate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-03'
group by uploadedby
```

Or if you do not want to repeat the `date_format()` then you can use a subquery:

```
select uploadedby,
  count(case when date = '01-01-2013' then uploadedby end) as `01-01-2013`,
  count(case when date = '01-02-2013' then uploadedby end) as `01-02-2013`        
from
(
  select uploadedby, date_format(uploaddate,'%m-%d-%Y') date
  from imsexport
  where uploaddate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-03'
) src
group by uploadedby
```

If you need to do this dynamically, then you could use a prepared statement in MySQL. Which will get the list of dates that need to be columns:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when date = ''',
      date_format(uploaddate,'%m-%d-%Y'),
      ''' then uploadedby end) AS `',
      date_format(uploaddate,'%m-%d-%Y'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM imsexport
where uploaddate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-03';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT uploadedby, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM
                  ( 
                    select uploadedby, date_format(uploaddate,''%m-%d-%Y'') date
                    from imsexport
                    where uploaddate between ''2013-01-01'' and ''2013-01-03''
                  ) src
                  GROUP BY uploadedby');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec418/3)

If you are worried that you might be missing dates, then I would suggest creating a calendar table that you would get the list of dates from and then you would join the calendar table to your `imsexport` table to make sure that you would have a list of all dates even if there were no uploads for the day.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried that too but encountered several problems. 1) The dates are dynamic and ranges upto two years, I can't figure out how to limit it to a specific date range. 2) How do I display that in HTML? 3) What happens if a specific date does not have an uploadedby count value?