# Viewing Attendance datewise using phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql, css

```
<?php require_once('Connections/dbconnect.php'); ?>
<?php
$c=$_GET['Class'];
$s=$_GET['Section'];
$f=$_GET['fmonth'];
$t=$_GET['tmonth'];
$count=1;
mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_classwise = "SELECT Name_of_Student, Roll_no, Section,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 1, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day1', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 2, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day2', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 3, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day3', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 4, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day4', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 5, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day5', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 6, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day6', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 7, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day7', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 8, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day8', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 9, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day9', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 10, `Status`, NULL)) AS'day10',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 11, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day11', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 12, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day12', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 13, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day13', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 14, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day14', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 15, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day15', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 16, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day16', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 17, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day17', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 18, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day18', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 19, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day19', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 20, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day20', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 21, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day21', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 22, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day22', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 23, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day23', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 24, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day24', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 25, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day25', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 26, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day26', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 27, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day27', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 28, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day28', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 29, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day29', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 30, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day30',  
GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`Date`) = 31, `Status`, NULL)) AS 'day31', 
COUNT(if(`Status`='Y', `Status`, NULL)) AS 'total' FROM `attendance`
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '$f' AND '$t' GROUP BY Name_of_Student" ;
$classwise = mysql_query($query_classwise, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_classwise = mysql_fetch_assoc($classwise);
$totalRows_classwise = mysql_num_rows($classwise);
?>
```

My query is very long, I don't understand whether my query is correct or not, My knowledge in php is very limited, I try to output using the following php code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #666600}
.style2 {color: #000000}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
<td width="48" bgcolor="#000000"><div align="center">SL No</div></td>
<td width="225" bgcolor="#000000"><div align="center">Name of Student</div></td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000"><div align="center">Roll no</div></td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000">Day 1 </td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000">Day 2</td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000">Day 3 </td>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#333333"><div align="center"><?php echo $count++; ?></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#333333"><?php echo $row_classwise['Name_of_Student']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#333333"><div align="center"><?php echo $row_classwise['Roll_no'];
?> </div></td>
<td bgcolor="#333333"><?php echo $row_classwise['day1']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#333333"><?php echo $row_classwise['day2']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#333333"><?php echo $row_classwise['day3']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_classwise = mysql_fetch_assoc($classwise)); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($classwise);
?>
```

I want to get the correct Y or N under each day(day1,day2,and so on) columns. So far it does not output the desired resultI can provide the table if necessary...

Here is my new query, I want to put -/- and - where the day is Saturday and Sunday or Holiday:

```
SELECT Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Class, Students.Section, allDays.aDay, 
GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(attendance.Status, '-') ORDER BY TimePeriod.`time` DESC SEPARATOR '/') AS Status
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name_of_Student, Roll_no, Class, Section FROM attendance ) AS Students
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS aDay UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION 
SELECT 10 AS aDay UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT 20 AS aDay UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29 UNION 
SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31) allDays
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Morning' AS `time` UNION SELECT 'Afternoon') TimePeriod
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance ON Students.Name_of_Student = attendance.Name_of_Student AND allDays.aDay = DAY(`Date`) 
AND BINARY TimePeriod.`time` = BINARY attendance.`time` where Date Between '$f' and '$t' and Students.Section='$s' and Students.Class='$c' 
GROUP BY Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Section, allDays.aDay 
ORDER BY Students.Name_of_Student, allDays.aDay
```

Comment: what is status in query does it contain 1,0 or what?

Comment: @Nomi For present `Y` and for Absent `N`

Comment: here you can find the table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468945/attendance-view/17469153?noredirect=1#comment25385300_17469153

Comment: wrong can you see the question is already marked with -3 then why did you followed it?

Comment: @Nomi Using the same table I try to make attendance view..I cannot find desired solution for this...if you can help me out, I would feel very much obliged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to get a whole line line that, probably easier to get a row per person per day. Then in your php code you throw a new line when the person changes.

SQL something like this:-

```
SELECT Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Section, allDays.aDay, attendence.Status
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name_of_Student FROM attendence WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '$f' AND '$t') AS Students
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT 1 AS aDay UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION 
SELECT 10 AS aDay UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT 20 AS aDay UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29 UNION 
SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31 
) allDays
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendence
ON Students.Name_of_Student = attendence.Name_of_Student AND allDays.aDay = DAY(`Date`)
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '$f' AND '$t'
```

This is getting a list of the students (which would be easier if you had a student table) and a list of all the days of the month. Then joining those with a left join  against attendence.

Your php would then be something like this (not tested)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #666600}
.style2 {color: #000000}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
<td width="48" bgcolor="#000000"><div align="center">SL No</div></td>
<td width="225" bgcolor="#000000"><div align="center">Name of Student</div></td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000"><div align="center">Roll no</div></td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000">Day 1 </td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000">Day 2</td>
<td width="45" bgcolor="#000000">Day 3 </td>
</tr>
<?php
$PrevName_of_Student = '';
while ($row_classwise = mysql_fetch_assoc($classwise))
{ 
    if ($PrevName_of_Student != $row_classwise['Name_of_Student'])
    {
        if ($PrevName_of_Student ! = '')
        {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?><tr>
        <td bgcolor="#333333"><div align="center"><?php echo $count++; ?></div></td>
        <td bgcolor="#333333"><?php echo $row_classwise['Name_of_Student']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#333333"><div align="center"><?php echo $row_classwise['Roll_no'];?></div></td>
        <?php
        $PrevName_of_Student = $row_classwise['Name_of_Student'];
    }
?>
    <td bgcolor="#333333"><?php echo $row_classwise['Status']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
if ($PrevName_of_Student ! = '')
{
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($classwise);
?>
```

Putting that together you get something like this (tested and working)

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
If (!$link) 
{
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db('testarea') or die ('Unable to select database');

$query = "SELECT Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Section, allDays.aDay, attendance.Status, TimePeriod.`time`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name_of_Student, Roll_no, Section FROM attendance ) AS Students
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT 1 AS aDay UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION 
SELECT 10 AS aDay UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT 20 AS aDay UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29 UNION 
SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31 
) allDays
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Morning' AS `time` UNION SELECT 'Afternoon') TimePeriod
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance
ON Students.Name_of_Student = attendance.Name_of_Student AND allDays.aDay = DAY(`Date`) AND BINARY TimePeriod.`time` = BINARY attendance.`time`
ORDER BY Students.Name_of_Student, allDays.aDay, TimePeriod.`time` DESC";

$classwise = mysql_query($query);

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #666600}
.style2 {color: #000000}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
<td width="48" ><div align="center">SL No</div></td>
<td width="225" ><div align="center">Name of Student</div></td>
<td width="45" ><div align="center">Roll no</div></td>
<?php
for($iCnt = 1; $iCnt <=31; $iCnt++)
{
    foreach(array("Morning", "Afternoon") AS $TimePeriod)
    {
        echo "<td width='45' >Day $iCnt $TimePeriod</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
$PrevName_of_Student = '';
$count = 0;
while ($row_classwise = mysql_fetch_assoc($classwise))
{ 
    if ($PrevName_of_Student != $row_classwise['Name_of_Student'])
    {
        if ($PrevName_of_Student != '')
        {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td ><div align='center'>".$count++."</div></td>";
        echo "<td >".$row_classwise['Name_of_Student']."</td>";
        echo "<td ><div align='center'>".$row_classwise['Roll_no']."</div></td>";
        $PrevName_of_Student = $row_classwise['Name_of_Student'];
    }
    echo "<td >".$row_classwise['Status']."</td>";
} 
if ($PrevName_of_Student != '')
{
    echo '</tr>';
}
mysql_free_result($classwise);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT - merge the morning and afternoon records for a day for a person:-

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
If (!$link) 
{
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db('testarea') or die ('Unable to select database');

$query = "SELECT Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Section, allDays.aDay, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(attendance.Status, '-') ORDER BY TimePeriod.`time` DESC SEPARATOR '/') AS Status
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name_of_Student, Roll_no, Section FROM attendance ) AS Students
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT 1 AS aDay UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION 
SELECT 10 AS aDay UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT 20 AS aDay UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29 UNION 
SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31 
) allDays
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Morning' AS `time` UNION SELECT 'Afternoon') TimePeriod
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance
ON Students.Name_of_Student = attendance.Name_of_Student AND allDays.aDay = DAY(`Date`) AND BINARY TimePeriod.`time` = BINARY attendance.`time`
GROUP BY Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Section, allDays.aDay
ORDER BY Students.Name_of_Student, allDays.aDay";

$classwise = mysql_query($query);

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #666600}
.style2 {color: #000000}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
<td width="48" ><div align="center">SL No</div></td>
<td width="225" ><div align="center">Name of Student</div></td>
<td width="45" ><div align="center">Roll no</div></td>
<?php
for($iCnt = 1; $iCnt <=31; $iCnt++)
{
    echo "<td width='45' >Day $iCnt </td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
$PrevName_of_Student = '';
$count = 0;
while ($row_classwise = mysql_fetch_assoc($classwise))
{ 
    if ($PrevName_of_Student != $row_classwise['Name_of_Student'])
    {
        if ($PrevName_of_Student != '')
        {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td ><div align='center'>".$count++."</div></td>";
        echo "<td >".$row_classwise['Name_of_Student']."</td>";
        echo "<td ><div align='center'>".$row_classwise['Roll_no']."</div></td>";
        $PrevName_of_Student = $row_classwise['Name_of_Student'];
    }
    echo "<td >".$row_classwise['Status']."</td>";
} 
if ($PrevName_of_Student != '')
{
    echo '</tr>';
}
mysql_free_result($classwise);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT - updated query.

Note I have put the clauses to limit the students within the sub select which gets the list of students. Further the check for dates I have put in the ON clause of the LEFT OUTER JOIN to get the actual attendance.  This was even if the student has not attended any classes in that time period they will still appear in the report (just with -/- for each day).

```
SELECT Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Class, Students.Section, allDays.aDay, 
GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(attendance.Status, '-') ORDER BY TimePeriod.`time` DESC SEPARATOR '/') AS Status
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name_of_Student, Roll_no, Class, Section FROM attendance where Section='$s' AND Class='$c' ) AS Students
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS aDay UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION 
SELECT 10 AS aDay UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT 20 AS aDay UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29 UNION 
SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31) allDays
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Morning' AS `time` UNION SELECT 'Afternoon') TimePeriod
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance ON Students.Name_of_Student = attendance.Name_of_Student AND allDays.aDay = DAY(`Date`) 
AND BINARY TimePeriod.`time` = BINARY attendance.`time` 
AND Date Between '$f' and '$t' 
GROUP BY Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Section, allDays.aDay 
ORDER BY Students.Name_of_Student, allDays.aDay
```

Comment: Thanks very very much. what I want to produce is something like this http://postimg.org/image/t46xc1laz/ Thank you very much again.

Comment: I have just tested your php code and comes up with blank...it does not print anything..

Comment: Your query is not also working...`unknown column Students.Roll_no`

Comment: Amended putting the SQL and php together and tested.

Comment: I removed `Students.Roll_no` and `Students.section` and the query is working in phpmyadmin. I pasted your php code as it is. But all I could get was blank...Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you changed the script to point at the database your table is on (in my version it is in the TestArea database on localhost).

Comment: Thanks a million..Now it's working great...I have one more question. How do I put total of `Y` in the last column? I have never seen like such a beautiful solution in Stack.

Comment: Yes I have changed the database to mine. It's working...But I want to use where clause For example  `where Class='$c' and Section='$s' and Date Between '$f' and '$t'`. I am confused where to put this where clause in the query. I am using `$c=$_GET['Class'];
$s=$_GET['Section'];
$f=$_GET['fmonth'];
$t=$_GET['tmonth'];`. And thanks again for your big help.

Comment: Put it between the line starting ON and the line starting ORDER. Note that you need to make sure that you use mysql_real_escape_string on those variables to avoid sql injection attacks on your web site.

Comment: thanks once again. Everything is fine now. In the output Day 1 appears two times for morning and afternoon, how do I merge Day 1 columns? I couldn't find where to use colspan. This will be my last question.

Comment: How do you want to merge the columns? I have added a slightly changed script that will put out one table cell per day for each person, with a slash between the morning and afternoon status (and a - if there is no status).

Comment: Thank you very much. One more thing is that `GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(attendance.Status, '-') ORDER BY TimePeriod.`time` DESC SEPARATOR '/')` does not work with `Where Clause`. This can be a problem as attendance should not be entered on Saturday and Sunday. However it works without Where Clause. My Where Clause is `WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013-07-01 AND '2013-07-31' AND Class='X' AND Section='A';`

Comment: Section is not unique in the SELECT so you need to specify which one. Change it to _Students.Section_

Comment: Not work. where I have made some changed in the query `SELECT Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Class, Students.Section, allDays.aDay, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(attendance.Status, '-') ORDER BY TimePeriod.`time` DESC SEPARATOR '/') AS Status FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name_of_Student, Roll_no, Class, Section FROM attendance ) AS Students` and `where Date Between '$f' and '$t' and Students.Section='$s' and Students.Class='$c' GROUP BY Students.Name_of_Student, Students.Roll_no, Students.Class, Students.Section, allDays.aDay ORDER BY Students.Name_of_Student, allDays.aDay";`

Comment: You have taken out the code required to give you the day of the month and the actual attendance (all that is left is the subselect to get the unique list of students). You also have an extra AND immediatly before the WHERE

Comment: I am just highlighting where I have added columns and where clause. And here is just a conjunction. I added WHERE clause in your query and as I need Class also, I have added Class in the subselect and Select command so that I can get it in my where clause...It seems fine at first, but it does not output -/- and - when it is Sunday and Saturday on which day attendance should not be likely entered. You have been a great help...

Comment: Can you add the full new SQL on here (either in the original post or as an extra reply)?

Comment: I have just paste my query. I want to put -/- and - when the day is Holiday. I am using your php script.

Comment: Done a few minor changes and posted the updated select above.